# I want to solve the slow loading of icons flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to solve the slow loading of icons, is there a Website that displays icons better and faster, I used Fontawsome, but I want to use the original in an easier way

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They updated the plugin today (15-12-2021) fixing this issue.
Update your plugin to version 63.2.4